# How to set value of response data of SOAP/XML-RPC Request to variable Jmeter?

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter, beanshell

I have 1 Thread Group with detail like this:
[image]

And here is my Regular Expression Extractor:

[image]

And here is my BeanShell PostProcessor:

[image]

And this is my response data:

```
&lt;NPWP&gt;999999999999999&lt;/NPWP&gt;
```

And this is my Error:

```
2017/08/21 12:06:15 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  // Get npwp from response data SO . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 7, column 68.  Encountered: "v" (118), after : "\"\\" 

2017/08/21 12:06:15 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  // Get npwp from response data SO . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 7, column 68.  Encountered: "v" (118), after : "\"\\"
```

Please help.

Thank you.

**===========================================================================**

Thank you Dmitri and user7294900, I can use both of your ways:

Groovy:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; // Import Library

npwp = vars.get("npwp"); // Get the value of response data of SOAP/XML-RPC Request

def myFile = new File(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\variable.txt"); // Open the file

myFile << "npwp = " + npwp + "\r\n"; // Write data to file

def fileContent = myFile.text; // Read data from file

log.info("Read from file: " + fileContent); // Print the file
```

BeanShell:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; // Import Library

npwp = vars.get("npwp"); // Get the value of response data of SOAP/XML-RPC Request

f = new FileOutputStream(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\variable.txt", true); // Open File(s)

p = new PrintStream(f);

p.println( "npwp = " + npwp ); // Write data to file

p.close();f.close(); // Close File(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change your Regular Expression to be `([0-9]+)` otherwise it will return only one digit
2. Switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, the relevant Groovy code would be something like:

   ```
   new File('variable.txt') << vars.get('npwp')
   ```

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [JMeter Best Practices: JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 1):

You have extra separator, you can use `getFullPathNoEndSeparator` function to remove it and add later `\\variable.txt`:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String baseDir = FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() );

f = new FileOutputStream(baseDir+"\\variable.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

change file type txt to csv it will work.. worked for me

See link for detailed steps and [Code to write parsed json variable value to file](https://www.automationtestingtutorials.com/2019/01/parsing-json-response-and-saving-it-in.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you can add the essential bits from the 3rd party resource directly to your answer please do so.